# Can't install PostgreSQL 9.2 on Linux Mint

Tags: linux, linux-mint, package-management, postgresql

I'm new with Linux systems. I tried to install PostgreSQL 9.2. I did the following:

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get -y install python-software-properties
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:pitti/postgresql
sudo apt-get update

sudo apt-get -y install postgresql-9.2 postgresql-client-9.2 postgresql-contrib-9.2
```

But it says that it can't find the packages. I read some tutorials and everywhere was written that I need to use the `ppa:pitti/postgresql` repository.

What's wrong?

**UPDATE1**

I successfully installed packages from @slm's answer, but I can't start postgres. When I try `psql` I get:

```
Command psql can be found in packages:
 * postgresql-client-common
 * postgres-xc-client
```

Also I don't see file `/etc/init.d/postgresql`.

**UPDATE2**

```
$ dpkg -L postgresql-contrib-9.2
/.
/usr
/usr/lib
/usr/lib/postgresql
/usr/lib/postgresql/9.2
/usr/lib/postgresql/9.2/lib
/usr/lib/postgresql/9.2/lib/test_parser.so
/usr/lib/postgresql/9.2/lib/btree_gist.so
/usr/lib/postgresql/9.2/lib/pgstattuple.so
/usr/lib/postgresql/9.2/lib/pg_buffercache.so
/usr/lib/postgresql/9.2/lib/cube.so
/usr/lib/postgresql/9.2/lib/unaccent.so
/usr/lib/postgresql/9.2/lib/earthdistance.so
/usr/lib/postgresql/9.2/lib/pgrowlocks.so
/usr/lib/postgresql/9.2/lib/insert_username.so
/usr/lib/postgresql/9.2/lib/moddatetime.so
/usr/lib/postgresql/9.2/lib/isn.so
 /usr/lib/postgresql/9.2/lib/lo.so
/usr/lib/postgresql/9.2/lib/chkpass.so
/usr/lib/postgresql/9.2/lib/passwordcheck.so
/usr/lib/postgresql/9.2/lib/pg_freespacemap.so
/usr/lib/postgresql/9.2/lib/auth_delay.so
/usr/lib/postgresql/9.2/lib/pgcrypto.so
/usr/lib/postgresql/9.2/lib/pgxml.so
/usr/lib/postgresql/9.2/lib/btree_gin.so
/usr/lib/postgresql/9.2/lib/seg.so
/usr/lib/postgresql/9.2/lib/tcn.so
/usr/lib/postgresql/9.2/lib/auto_explain.so
/usr/lib/postgresql/9.2/lib/file_fdw.so
/usr/lib/postgresql/9.2/lib/uuid-ossp.so
/usr/lib/postgresql/9.2/lib/refint.so
/usr/lib/postgresql/9.2/lib/dict_int.so
/usr/lib/postgresql/9.2/lib/ltree.so
/usr/lib/postgresql/9.2/lib/tablefunc.so
/usr/lib/postgresql/9.2/lib/dummy_seclabel.so
/usr/lib/postgresql/9.2/lib/dict_xsyn.so
/usr/lib/postgresql/9.2/lib/adminpack.so
/usr/lib/postgresql/9.2/lib/fuzzystrmatch.so
/usr/lib/postgresql/9.2/lib/pg_trgm.so
/usr/lib/postgresql/9.2/lib/pg_stat_statements.so
/usr/lib/postgresql/9.2/lib/autoinc.so
/usr/lib/postgresql/9.2/lib/timetravel.so
/usr/lib/postgresql/9.2/lib/dblink.so
/usr/lib/postgresql/9.2/lib/sslinfo.so
/usr/lib/postgresql/9.2/lib/_int.so
/usr/lib/postgresql/9.2/lib/hstore.so
/usr/lib/postgresql/9.2/lib/pageinspect.so
/usr/lib/postgresql/9.2/lib/citext.so
/usr/lib/postgresql/9.2/bin
/usr/lib/postgresql/9.2/bin/pgbench
/usr/lib/postgresql/9.2/bin/pg_standby
/usr/lib/postgresql/9.2/bin/pg_archivecleanup
/usr/lib/postgresql/9.2/bin/vacuumlo
/usr/lib/postgresql/9.2/bin/pg_test_timing
/usr/lib/postgresql/9.2/bin/pg_test_fsync
/usr/lib/postgresql/9.2/bin/oid2name
/usr/share
/usr/share/doc
/usr/share/doc/postgresql-contrib-9.2
/usr/share/doc/postgresql-contrib-9.2/copyright
/usr/share/doc/postgresql-contrib-9.2/autoinc.example
/usr/share/doc/postgresql-contrib-9.2/changelog.gz
 /usr/share/doc/postgresql-contrib-9.2/changelog.Debian.gz
/usr/share/doc/postgresql-contrib-9.2/moddatetime.example
/usr/share/doc/postgresql-contrib-9.2/refint.example
/usr/share/doc/postgresql-contrib-9.2/insert_username.example
/usr/share/doc/postgresql-contrib-9.2/timetravel.example
 /usr/share/postgresql
/usr/share/postgresql/9.2
/usr/share/postgresql/9.2/extension
/usr/share/postgresql/9.2/extension/pgstattuple.control
/usr/share/postgresql/9.2/extension/uuid-ossp.control
/usr/share/postgresql/9.2/extension/dblink--1.0.sql
/usr/share/postgresql/9.2/extension/dblink.control
/usr/share/postgresql/9.2/extension/timetravel.control
/usr/share/postgresql/9.2/extension/citext.control
/usr/share/postgresql/9.2/extension/xml2--unpackaged--1.0.sql
/usr/share/postgresql/9.2/extension/isn.control
/usr/share/postgresql/9.2/extension/pageinspect.control
/usr/share/postgresql/9.2/extension/intarray.control
/usr/share/postgresql/9.2/extension/insert_username--unpackaged--1.0.sql
/usr/share/postgresql/9.2/extension/refint--unpackaged--1.0.sql
/usr/share/postgresql/9.2/extension/seg--1.0.sql
/usr/share/postgresql/9.2/extension/pg_stat_statements.control
/usr/share/postgresql/9.2/extension/tcn--1.0.sql
/usr/share/postgresql/9.2/extension/refint.control
/usr/share/postgresql/9.2/extension/lo--1.0.sql
/usr/share/postgresql/9.2/extension/pageinspect--unpackaged--1.0.sql
/usr/share/postgresql/9.2/extension/isn--1.0.sql
/usr/share/postgresql/9.2/extension/tablefunc--1.0.sql
/usr/share/postgresql/9.2/extension/test_parser--1.0.sql
/usr/share/postgresql/9.2/extension/sslinfo--unpackaged--1.0.sql
 /usr/share/postgresql/9.2/extension/moddatetime.control
/usr/share/postgresql/9.2/extension/intagg.control
/usr/share/postgresql/9.2/extension/timetravel--unpackaged--1.0.sql
/usr/share/postgresql/9.2/extension/insert_username.control
/usr/share/postgresql/9.2/extension/hstore--1.0--1.1.sql
/usr/share/postgresql/9.2/extension/moddatetime--1.0.sql
/usr/share/postgresql/9.2/extension/file_fdw--1.0.sql
/usr/share/postgresql/9.2/extension/tsearch2--unpackaged--1.0.sql
/usr/share/postgresql/9.2/extension/pg_freespacemap--unpackaged--1.0.sql
/usr/share/postgresql/9.2/extension/pg_stat_statements--1.0--1.1.sql
/usr/share/postgresql/9.2/extension/isn--unpackaged--1.0.sql
/usr/share/postgresql/9.2/extension/pg_trgm--unpackaged--1.0.sql
/usr/share/postgresql/9.2/extension/btree_gist--unpackaged--1.0.sql
/usr/share/postgresql/9.2/extension/earthdistance--unpackaged--1.0.sql
/usr/share/postgresql/9.2/extension/refint--1.0.sql
/usr/share/postgresql/9.2/extension/btree_gin--1.0.sql
/usr/share/postgresql/9.2/extension/autoinc.control
/usr/share/postgresql/9.2/extension/pgcrypto.control
/usr/share/postgresql/9.2/extension/pg_trgm.control
/usr/share/postgresql/9.2/extension/btree_gin.control
/usr/share/postgresql/9.2/extension/seg.control
/usr/share/postgresql/9.2/extension/pg_trgm--1.0.sql
/usr/share/postgresql/9.2/extension/hstore--1.1.sql
/usr/share/postgresql/9.2/extension/test_parser.control
/usr/share/postgresql/9.2/extension/dict_xsyn--1.0.sql
/usr/share/postgresql/9.2/extension/sslinfo--1.0.sql
/usr/share/postgresql/9.2/extension/tablefunc--unpackaged--1.0.sql
/usr/share/postgresql/9.2/extension/tcn.control
/usr/share/postgresql/9.2/extension/lo.control
/usr/share/postgresql/9.2/extension/uuid-ossp--1.0.sql
/usr/share/postgresql/9.2/extension/chkpass.control
/usr/share/postgresql/9.2/extension/btree_gin--unpackaged--1.0.sql
/usr/share/postgresql/9.2/extension/fuzzystrmatch.control
/usr/share/postgresql/9.2/extension/timetravel--1.0.sql
/usr/share/postgresql/9.2/extension/cube--1.0.sql
/usr/share/postgresql/9.2/extension/dblink--unpackaged--1.0.sql
/usr/share/postgresql/9.2/extension/insert_username--1.0.sql
/usr/share/postgresql/9.2/extension/ltree--1.0.sql
/usr/share/postgresql/9.2/extension/citext--unpackaged--1.0.sql
/usr/share/postgresql/9.2/extension/ltree--unpackaged--1.0.sql
/usr/share/postgresql/9.2/extension/pgstattuple--unpackaged--1.0.sql
/usr/share/postgresql/9.2/extension/btree_gist--1.0.sql
/usr/share/postgresql/9.2/extension/dict_xsyn.control
/usr/share/postgresql/9.2/extension/pgcrypto--1.0.sql
/usr/share/postgresql/9.2/extension/uuid-ossp--unpackaged--1.0.sql
/usr/share/postgresql/9.2/extension/pg_buffercache--1.0.sql
/usr/share/postgresql/9.2/extension/unaccent--unpackaged--1.0.sql
/usr/share/postgresql/9.2/extension/seg--unpackaged--1.0.sql
/usr/share/postgresql/9.2/extension/file_fdw.control
/usr/share/postgresql/9.2/extension/tsearch2--1.0.sql
/usr/share/postgresql/9.2/extension/fuzzystrmatch--unpackaged--1.0.sql
/usr/share/postgresql/9.2/extension/lo--unpackaged--1.0.sql
/usr/share/postgresql/9.2/extension/unaccent--1.0.sql
/usr/share/postgresql/9.2/extension/fuzzystrmatch--1.0.sql
/usr/share/postgresql/9.2/extension/intarray--unpackaged--1.0.sql
/usr/share/postgresql/9.2/extension/autoinc--unpackaged--1.0.sql
/usr/share/postgresql/9.2/extension/ltree.control
/usr/share/postgresql/9.2/extension/pg_buffercache--unpackaged--1.0.sql
/usr/share/postgresql/9.2/extension/cube.control
/usr/share/postgresql/9.2/extension/pgcrypto--unpackaged--1.0.sql
/usr/share/postgresql/9.2/extension/chkpass--1.0.sql
/usr/share/postgresql/9.2/extension/earthdistance--1.0.sql
/usr/share/postgresql/9.2/extension/pg_stat_statements--1.1.sql
/usr/share/postgresql/9.2/extension/pgrowlocks--unpackaged--1.0.sql
/usr/share/postgresql/9.2/extension/pgrowlocks--1.0.sql
/usr/share/postgresql/9.2/extension/moddatetime--unpackaged--1.0.sql
/usr/share/postgresql/9.2/extension/unaccent.control
/usr/share/postgresql/9.2/extension/dict_int--unpackaged--1.0.sql
/usr/share/postgresql/9.2/extension/intarray--1.0.sql
/usr/share/postgresql/9.2/extension/pgstattuple--1.0.sql
/usr/share/postgresql/9.2/extension/pg_freespacemap--1.0.sql
/usr/share/postgresql/9.2/extension/autoinc--1.0.sql
/usr/share/postgresql/9.2/extension/tsearch2.control
/usr/share/postgresql/9.2/extension/test_parser--unpackaged--1.0.sql
/usr/share/postgresql/9.2/extension/pageinspect--1.0.sql
/usr/share/postgresql/9.2/extension/pg_freespacemap.control
/usr/share/postgresql/9.2/extension/xml2--1.0.sql
/usr/share/postgresql/9.2/extension/citext--1.0.sql
/usr/share/postgresql/9.2/extension/chkpass--unpackaged--1.0.sql
/usr/share/postgresql/9.2/extension/hstore--unpackaged--1.0.sql
/usr/share/postgresql/9.2/extension/dict_int--1.0.sql
/usr/share/postgresql/9.2/extension/hstore.control
/usr/share/postgresql/9.2/extension/intagg--unpackaged--1.0.sql
/usr/share/postgresql/9.2/extension/xml2.control
/usr/share/postgresql/9.2/extension/pgrowlocks.control
/usr/share/postgresql/9.2/extension/sslinfo.control
/usr/share/postgresql/9.2/extension/cube--unpackaged--1.0.sql
/usr/share/postgresql/9.2/extension/adminpack--1.0.sql
/usr/share/postgresql/9.2/extension/pg_buffercache.control
 /usr/share/postgresql/9.2/extension/pg_stat_statements--unpackaged--1.0.sql
/usr/share/postgresql/9.2/extension/btree_gist.control
/usr/share/postgresql/9.2/extension/intagg--1.0.sql
/usr/share/postgresql/9.2/extension/adminpack.control
/usr/share/postgresql/9.2/extension/dict_int.control
/usr/share/postgresql/9.2/extension/tablefunc.control
/usr/share/postgresql/9.2/extension/earthdistance.control
/usr/share/postgresql/9.2/man
/usr/share/postgresql/9.2/man/man1
/usr/share/postgresql/9.2/man/man1/pg_test_timing.1.gz
/usr/share/postgresql/9.2/man/man1/pg_test_fsync.1.gz
/usr/share/postgresql/9.2/man/man1/pg_standby.1.gz
/usr/share/postgresql/9.2/man/man1/pgbench.1.gz
/usr/share/postgresql/9.2/man/man1/oid2name.1.gz
/usr/share/postgresql/9.2/man/man1/pg_archivecleanup.1.gz
/usr/share/postgresql/9.2/man/man1/vacuumlo.1.gz
```

Comment: What version of Linux Mint are you using?

Comment: @slm:Mint Olivia.

Comment: The directions I gave you should work then.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You might want to try the directions described in this post titled: [Install latest PostgreSQL on Linux Mint](http://gbteknotes.blogspot.com/2013/05/install-latest-postgresql-on-linux-mint.html). General steps:

1. create /etc/apt/sources.list.d/pgdg.list containing:

   ```
   deb http://apt.postgresql.org/pub/repos/apt/ precise-pgdg main
   ```
2. Import the repository signing key, and update the package lists

   ```
   $ wget --quiet -O - https://www.postgresql.org/media/keys/ACCC4CF8.asc | \
     sudo apt-key add -
   ```
3. Update repository indexes

   ```
   $ sudo apt-get update
   ```
4. Install postgreSQL (run all these cmds as root)

   ```
   $ sudo apt-get install postgresql-9.2
   $ sudo apt-get install postgresql-contrib-9.2
   $ sudo apt-get install pgadmin3
   ```

Comment: I install this packages. Create Os user postgres. Make `su postgres`. But itst says that cant find command `psql`.

Comment: @KliverMax - good. The link I provided had more steps for setting the master password and such, so you might want to refer to it for all the steps. Please mark this answer as accepted if your issue's been resolved so others know you're all set.

Comment: :Also i cant find file /etc/init.d/postgresql.

Comment: @KliverMax - you can use the command `dpkg -L <pkg>` to list the contents of the packages you just installed. I'll list them out and look for the init.d script to see if it's included.

Comment: i try `dpkg -L <pkg>` but get `syntax error near 'newLine'`.

Comment: @KliverMax - the `<pkg>` is a placeholder for the names of the package files I mentioned in my answer, mainly: postgresql-9.2, postgresql-contrib-9.2, etc. Try this: `dpkg -L postgresql-contrib-9.2` for e.g.

Comment: i cant find init.d script. I put output in question update.

Comment: @KliverMax - were you able to locate the init.d script? Look inside the other package too, `dpkg -L postgresql-9.2`.

Comment: The apt-get wasn't happy with the _sudo_ in `sudo deb http://apt.postgresql.org/pub/repos/apt/ precise-pgdg main`. If there's not a good reason to include it in your answer, you man want to remove it since it doesn't appear in the linked article.

Comment: @kindasimple - thanks fixed. That's actually a typo on my part.

Answer (score 0):

If psql is not working, may be it is not there in PATH. Try doing a find for psql and see if it is there.